# How in the OC call Microsoft Text To Speech this api, I can not complete the URL synthesis

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech, bing

How in the OC call Microsoft Text To Speech this api, I can not complete the URL synthesis.I can not read SSML W3C Specification.
please.Can you provide examples?

Comment: It might be hard for your to explain things, but you need to provide more details if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply..On Microsoft Text-to-speech there is no demo can refer to?

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS